# Is WPF's Application.Exit event called when shutting down ungracefully?

Tags: wpf

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.exit?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Application.Exit);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) for Application.Exit states:

> Occurs just before an application shuts down, and cannot be canceled.

and

> An application can shut down for either of the following reasons:
>
> - The Shutdown method of the Application object is called, either explicitly or as determined by the ShutdownMode property.
> - The user ends the session by logging off or shutting down.

What is not clear to me is if this event still executes when the application is shutting down ungracefully. For example, when there is an unhandled exception, or if the user ends the process via Task Manager.

**Is WPF's Application.Exit event called when shutting down ungracefully?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exit event doesn't raise on kill and closing due unhandled exception events. 
For the last one you can use DispatcherUnhandledException (that is not raised when you kill the process).